# Error when push commit to gitlab, pipeline error could not read Username

Tags: laravel, git, gitlab, ssh-keys, cicd

When I commit changes to gitlab and deploying project on cpanel. but got this error in pipeline.
i am using laravel deployer in this project, i want to deploy my project on cpanel through gitlab.

```
The command "cd /home/sfd/public_html && (/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/pa  
  th-bin/git clone   --recursive  https://gitlab.com/nas-project  
  .git /home/sfd/public_html/releases/1 2>&1)" failed.                         
                                                                               
  Exit Code: 128 (Invalid exit argument)                                       
                                                                               
  Host Name: 51.75.174.102                                                     
                                                                               
  ================                                                             
  Cloning into '/home/sfd/public_html/releases/1'...                           
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or   
  address
```

here i'm posting my some code, (runner code, gitlab-ci.yml, deploy code)

**runner code**

```
[[runners]]
  name = "DESKTOP-1OOOT34"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/nas-project.git"
  token = "mytoken"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

**Deploy.php code**

```
<?php
return [
    'default' => 'basic',

    'strategies' => [
        //
    ],
    'hooks' => [
        'ready' => [
            'artisan:storage:link',
            'artisan:view:clear',
            'artisan:config:cache',
            'artisan:migrate',
        ],
    ],
    'options' => [
        'application' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
        'repository' => 'https://gitlab.com/n1063/suntop/nas-project.git',
    ],
    'hosts' => [
        'mysiteIP' => [
            'deploy_path' => '/home/sfd/public_html',
            'user' => 'sfd',
            'multiplexing' => true,
                'sshOptions'   => [
                    'StrictHostKeyChecking' => 'no',
                    // ...
                  ],
            ],
    ],
    'localhost' => [
        //
    ],
    'include' => [
        //
    ],
    'custom_deployer_file' => false,

];
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:7.4

stages:
  - preparation
  - deploy
composer:
  stage: preparation
  script:
    - php -v
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --no-suggest
    - cp .env.example .env
    - php artisan key:generate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
  cache:
    paths:
      - vendor/

yarn:
  stage: preparation
  script:
    - yarn --version
    - yarn install --pure-lockfile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always


.init_ssh_live: &init_ssh_live |
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - *init_ssh_live
    - php artisan deploy mySiteIP -s upload
  environment:
    name: live
    url: mySiteIP
  only:
    - dev
```

Comment: When using https, you're not using ssh. Why is this tagged [tag:ssh-keys] when you're using an `https://` URL? (Perhaps that's the entire error, that you should be using an ssh URL?)

Comment: @torek so i use ssh URL in deploy file where i'm putting git htts url ?

Comment: That's generally how I would do this sort of thing. Generate a machine key and use that when having the machine access a private repository.

Comment: can you please explain this to me a lil ? I'm stuck in this problem from last 3 days. please tell me in which file i made change ? above i mentioned 2 files with their code, (deploy.php | gitlab-ci.yml). please help me @torek

Comment: I haven't ever used GitLab's pipelines and CI system, so I don't know any specifics there. But in general, when you have some machine-user (build software) clone a repository, it's not running on behalf of some *user*, so there's no user name or user key available. So you use an `ssh://git@<host>/path/to/repo.git` URL and make sure that *this* ssh command runs with `$HOME/.ssh/` set up so that it sends an ssh key that's authorized to read the URL from the given host.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy Laravel project on cPanel server through GitLab without any package then this might help you. Config detail is in description https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2238596

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30873628)